# Why doesn't "code folding" work in my ACE editor?

Tags: ace-editor

We have been using the ACE editor with our conversation management tool for a couple years. We use it almost exclusively to edit XML files and it works fine as a simple text editor with XML highlighting. But, it does not do code folding (or other things like indentation markers). I have pasted some of our XML into other vanilla ACE editors (kitchen sink demo, and others) and folding and indents work as I would expect. It does not work with the simple "editor.html" provided with the ACE 2.0 release. What am I missing? How do I enable folding in my instance of the editor?

Here is the HTML that instances a working (but not folding) editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>ejEditor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="misc/ejTalker.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
  <script language="JavaScript" src= "ejJScript/ejTalkBrowser.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src= "ejJScript/ejTalkerAPI.js"></script>

  <script src="ejJScript/aceSrc/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  </script>
  <script src="ejJScript/aceSrc/theme-eclipse.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="ejJScript/aceSrc/mode-xml.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script>
    var ejEditor;

    function startEditor(){
      ejEditor = ace.edit( "ejEditor" );
      ejEditor.setTheme( "ace/theme/eclipse" );
      var xmlMode = require( "ace/mode/xml" ).Mode;
      ejEditor.getSession().setMode( new xmlMode() );

      document.getElementById('ejEditor').style.fontSize='medium';
      document.getElementById('ejEditor').style.fontWeight='bold';
      ejEditor.setBehavioursEnabled( true );

      appLoadFileEdit();
    }
  </script>
  <style>

    #ejEditor { 
      position: absolute;
      top:  150px;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background: white;
    }
</head>
<body onload="startEditor();">
  <table>
    <tr><td> *** some of our display stuff *** </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="10" align="left"><pre id="ejEditor"></pre></td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ace 2.0 release the latest one atm. is 1.1.6. Maybe you are using  0.2.0 which is very old and doesn't have folding yet.

Comment: Found the problem: "2011.08.02, Version 0.2.0" is the latest reference on https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/downloads BUT this handy bookmark was an abandoned link? Had not worked on this editor for a while and  did not notice that it moved to: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/

Comment: github disabled downloads pages 1.5 years ago and added releases page instead https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/releases